# Where should I store an OAuth refresh token for a third party?

Tags: authentication, oauth, api, authorization, oauth2

I am connecting to a third party which authenticates with OAuth2. Once the user has logged in, I want to store the access & refresh tokens for the user. Which is more secure & proper - to save the refresh to the database & foreign key it to the user, or to store it as a cookie?